# How to copy folder from Ubuntu to mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a virtual box installed with Ubuntu on it. I want to copy a folder from Ubuntu to my local machine i.e. Macbook.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Yes, there is a way; But it depends upon the system configuration. And the question is off-topic here (since related to system administration), and you don't give enough details

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. I do it to copy files from Windows to my Ubuntu virual machine. To do so, you have to:

1) Once you have launched your VM, in the top menu, select "Devices -> Install Guest Additions". After that, the Guest Additions .iso will be loaded.

2) You will see the .iso loaded as a CD image. Run it and it will launch the install process in a Terminal. Follow the instructions until the end of the install process.

3) Reboot your VM.

4) Run you VM, in the top menu, select "Devices -> Shared Folder Settings", click in [image] to add a new folder, and select the name and the route of the Shared Folder (for example, a folder with name LINUX created in your Mac).

[image]

5) Now, go back to your Ubuntu VM, open a terminal and write (again, the name of the folder is just an example. In this case, both folders, Mac and Ubuntu shared folders share the same name):

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/LINUX 
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf LINUX /media/LINUX
```

6) Finally, if you want to mount the shared folder automatically every team you run your VM, do:

```
$ gksudo gedit /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

And add the following line:

```
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf LINUX /media/LINUX
```

Hope it works!